# Does IE 10 support the following chiper suites?

Tags: security, internet-explorer

does IE 10 support the following two chipher suites:

- TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
- TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA

Can't find anything relating to it 
only this one: (which says: NO!)
https://github.com/client9/sslassert/wiki/IE-Supported-Cipher-Suites

Best Regards
Markus

Comment: I don't think so. 11 doesn't. I don't have an IE10 machine, but assuming you do, you can check using this: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html

Comment: Thanks, according to this page, IE 10 does not. THX. (Can you post a "real answer", so that I can mark it as solved?)

Comment: But why? Is it because CBC does not seem to be a good mode in light of the beast attack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't. You can check what suites a browser supports using [this page](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html)